# Remove User.config At the Time of uninstalling The The Program

Tags: c#, .net, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

Hi I Need help for uninstalling The user.config File at the time uninstalling my program, because at the time of installation i am assignig Setting.

butEven  After Uninstalling my software at the time of new installation i got the same settings it is not removing that user.config file in application data folder

What i need to do Kindly help me for this....

Answer (score 0):

You should provide yours installation package with custom actions and on uninstalling remove config manually.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can read about custom actions in setup project

Comment: hey thanks for the answer , but can u guide me guidense on how to remove my file from application data Folder  ???